# How to set ACL permissions freebsd

Tags: freebsd, acl

```
unix# setfacl -d -m group:smid_r:r /dat/samba/data/user/smit
setfacl: /dat/samba/data/user/smit: acl_calc_mask() failed: Invalid argument
setfacl: /dat/samba/data/user/smit: failed to set ACL mask
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I thought ACL is a Windows-only feature...

Comment: No this feature was first released in unix systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first set this mandatory elements.

setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::,mask::rwx /dat/samba/data/user/smid